# Is it possible to hold down element.click for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, svelte

Context: Creating a keyboard element in svelte, i want to emulate a user click to show the animation, but `btn.click()` is to short to show the transition.

Using `btn.click()` does fire a click element, but it's too short for the user to notice.

Ive tried using `btn.focus()` and `btn.blur()` but it doesn't play the animation, it only causes a border to show up.

Is there a way for me to emulate a click for **X** amount of time?
This is my code (per key)

```html
<script lang=ts>
    import { addLetter, enter, removeLetter, onKeyPress } from "./state";
    export let key: string;
    let btn: HTMLButtonElement;
    function handle(e: MouseEvent) {
        if(!e.isTrusted) return
        if(key === "DELETE") {
            removeLetter(false)
        } else if(key === "ENTER") {
            enter(false)
        } else {
            addLetter(key, false)
        }
    }

    onKeyPress((k, kb) => {
        if(!(k === key) || !kb) return
        btn.click() //! LOOK HERE
    })
</script>

<button class="btn kbd transition-all" bind:this={btn} on:click={handle}>{key}</button>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) events

Comment: @Mina this question is how to programatically hold the button for a certain amount of time. not detecting if the user is holding the button for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run an animation rather than using transitions, e.g.

```html
<script>
    let button;
    function onKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.key == 'f') {
            animate();
        }
    }
    
    function animate() {
        button.animate(
            [{ background: 'red' }],
            { duration: 200, direction: 'alternate', iterations: 2 },
        )
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:keydown={onKeyDown}/>

<button bind:this={button} on:click={animate}>F</button>
```

[Single Key](https://svelte.dev/repl/5699c4b86c1643d6b4a0b8ec630320f3?version=3.50.0)
[Full Keyboard](https://svelte.dev/repl/25ada529856e4a84a1e7e4b8905cddf8?version=3.50.0)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) events

```
<script lang=ts>
    import { addLetter, enter, removeLetter, onKeyPress } from "./state";
    export let key: string;
    let btn: HTMLButtonElement;
    let mousedownTime: Date;
    function handle(e: MouseEvent) {
        if(!e.isTrusted) return
        if(key === "DELETE") {
            removeLetter(false)
        } else if(key === "ENTER") {
            enter(false)
        } else {
            addLetter(key, false)
        }
    }

    function mouseDown() => {
       mousedownTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    function mouseUp() {
        const mouseupTime = new Date().getTime(),
        timeDifference = mouseupTime - mousedownTime;
        alert(`Button held down for ${timeDifference}ms`);
    }

    onKeyPress((k, kb) => {
        if(!(k === key) || !kb) return
        btn.click() //! LOOK HERE
    })
</script>

<button class="btn kbd transition-all" bind:this={btn} on:mousedown={mouseDown} on:mouseup={mouseup}></button>
```